# Linux: Program/command to intentionally use lots of RAM

Tags: linux

I am writing a memory management program for linux, and I was wondering if there was an easy way to increase RAM usage significantly, so I can accurately check if my program is monitoring the RAM correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool that solves your problem called `stress` http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/. This tool can be used to generate even CPU, memory and IO load.

It should be available on POSIX compatible systems.